# prove by epsilon-delta

Tags: calculus, limits

Prove by epsilon-delta that if :

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
5 - x ,  & \text{if } x \notin \mathbb Q \\
x+1, & \text{if } x \in \mathbb Q
\end{cases}$$

then
$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ does not exist!

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Have you looked at examples of similar questions? If so, what was it about them that you couldn't understand?

Comment: i said lets suppose by contradiction that the lim does exists but could not reach impugnation @WillR

Comment: Number $g$ would be a limit of $f$ at $0$ if, for arbitrarily small neighborhood $G$ of $g$, there is small enough neighborhood $K$ of $0$, that for each $x\in K$ we have $f(x)\in G$. Hovewer, for rational $x$-es approaching zero, $f$ approaches $1$, whilst for irrationals it goes to $5$. So whatever samll $K$ you take, you'll get $f$ values differing by almost $5$, consequently not 'grouping' around any $g$ – hence no limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show that no number $L$ can satisfy the definition of the limit. This means that for all real numbers $L$, you must show that there's an $\varepsilon > 0$, such that for all $\delta > 0$, there is some $x$ such that $0<|x-a| < \delta$ but still $|f(x)-L| \ge \varepsilon$.

Here's a start, you can try to formalize/complete this argument.

For $L=5$, you can take $\varepsilon = 1$ and you'll have $|f(x)-5| \ge \varepsilon = 1$ in any neighborhood of $x=0$ because there are infinitely many rational numbers near $0$ which are mapped close to $1$.

Vice versa, for $L=1$, you can take $\varepsilon = 1$ again because there are infinitely many irrational numbers near $0$ which are mapped close to $5$, so $|f(x)-1| \ge \varepsilon = 1$.

For $L \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 1,5 \}$, you can take $\varepsilon = \min\left\{ \frac{|L-1|}{2}, \frac{|L-5|}{2} \right\}$ and then it doesn't matter if $x$ is rational or not, $|f(x)-L| \ge \varepsilon$ will hold for all $x$ sufficiently close to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's give this a try. Let $\epsilon$ be given and as such we suppose we have a $\delta$ that satesfies it.

we have then that $|x|<\delta$, as we approch $0$. We supposedly have then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ however we have that by nature of the function that $|5-x-L|<\epsilon$ and $|x+1-L|<\epsilon$ must be true when $|x|<\delta$. This is however not possible as there are the evident constraints of $|5-L|$ and $|1-L|$ for arbitrarily small $x$, meaning it'll always exceed a sufficiently small $\epsilon$ regardless of how small of a $\delta$ you have